# LINQ where clause based on (casted) interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to filter an entity list which implements an interface.

**Model:**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id {get; set;}
}

public interface IOther
{
    int Other {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntity : IEntity, IOther
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Other {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public abstract class GenericApiController<T> : ApiController
    where T : IEntity
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int other)
    {
        var query = Repository.AsQueryable()
                              .Cast<IOther>()
                              .Where(x => x.Other == other);

        return Ok(query.ToList());
    }
}
```

However I'm getting an "*LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types*" exception.

One solution would be to have `where T : IOther` on GenericApiController, but sadly I cannot do that as not every IEntity also implements IOther.

I was looking into if it was possible to do something like the following:

```
public abstract class GenericApiController<T> : ApiController
    where T : IEntity
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int other)
        where T : IOther
    {
        var query = Repository.AsQueryable()
                              .Where(x => x.Other == other);

        return Ok(query.ToList());
    }
}
```

Note the extra constraint on `Get()`, but that's not possible (to my knowledge).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your model won't compile, because MyEntity does not implement IOther

Comment: Whoops, fixed :) there was a few other errors as well. It's sort of pseudo code. Should get the message across.

Comment: Why not have another generic for the other interface as well?

Comment: @AD.Net I consider that a last resort, as I don't like multiple "base" generic controllers. But it might be the only way

Comment: @AD.Net On second thought another generic controller might not be as terrible a solution as I initially thought. I'll try it out :)

Comment: You're not showing the main piece of the puzzle: the `Repository`. Can you show how it's impleemnted? Most probably this is teh piece that shpould be generic to support what you want to do.

Comment: @Snæbjørn Is my answer solve your problem? If yes, thank you mark it as accepted. Otherwise, thank you to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a specific controller for classes inheriting `IOther` but it does not completely solve the problem.

In the expression below (`Repository` is a `IQueryable<T>` and `T` inherits from `IOther`), the C# compiler considers an implicit cast from `T` to `IOther` to make the call to the `Other` property.

```
var query = Repository.Where(x => x.Other == other);
```

So you get the same `NotSupportedException` about cast and LINQ to entities.

**The solution is to build the query at runtime using Reflection**.

This is to limit the compiler work at the expression level and to perform the transformation from an expression to a function at runtime.

The generic query expression is:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, int, IQueryable<T>>> QueryExpression =
    (repository, other) => repository.Where(x => x.Other == other);
```

Using a debug console you see how the compiler added an implicit converter:

QueryExpression.ToString() : (repository, other) => repository.Where(x => (**Convert(x)**.Other == other))

There are 2 things to change in this expression:

- Eliminate the use of converter
- Calling the `Other` property declared by `T` and not that declared by `IOther`

For this, we use an `ExpressionVisitor`.

```
public abstract class GenericApiControllerForIOther<T> : ApiController
    where T : IOther
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int other)
    {
        var query = QueryFunction(Repository, other);
        return Ok(query.ToList());
    }

    // the generic query expression
    static Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, int, IQueryable<T>>> QueryExpression =
        (repository, other) => repository.Where(x => x.Other == other);

    // the function built from the generci expression
    static Func<IQueryable<T>, int, IQueryable<T>> queryFunction = null;
    static Func<IQueryable<T>, int, IQueryable<T>> QueryFunction
    {
        get
        {
            if (queryFunction == null)
            {
                // rebuild a new lambda expression without reference to the IOther type
                TypeReplacer replacer = new TypeReplacer(typeof(IOther), typeof(T));
                Expression newExp = replacer.Visit(QueryExpression.Body);
                Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, int, IQueryable<T>>> newLambdaExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<T>, int, IQueryable<T>>>(newExp, QueryExpression.Parameters);
                // newLambdaExp.ToString(): (repository, other) => repository.Where(x => (x.Other == other))
                // convert the expression to a function
                queryFunction = newLambdaExp.Compile();
            }
            return queryFunction;
        }
    }

    class TypeReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public TypeReplacer(Type oldType, Type newType)
        {
            OldType = oldType;
            NewType = newType;
        }

        Type OldType;
        Type NewType;

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            // replace IOther.Property by T.Property
            MemberInfo memberInfo = node.Member;
            if (memberInfo.DeclaringType == OldType)
            {
                MemberInfo newMemberInfo = NewType.GetMember(memberInfo.Name).First();
                return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Visit(node.Expression), newMemberInfo);
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
        {
            // remove the Convert operator
            if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
                && node.Type == OldType
                && node.Operand.Type == NewType)
                return node.Operand;
            return base.VisitUnary(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to implement IEnumerable interface in IOther?

```
public interface IOther : IEnumerable
{
    int Other {get; set;}
}
```